# Fitting a new tyre and cassette

Tags: tire, repair

Hello I recently had one of the cogs on my cassette snap due to lack of care on my side obviously (the smallest one). This occurred due to my chain skipping and putting an unfortunate amount of force on the last cog.

I have ordered a new wheel and cassette and everything is ready to be placed onto the bike but I wanted to know as I physically couldn’t operate the wheel due to the snapped cog, the gear hasn’t been shifted to the highest option or smallest cog. How do I combat this when fitting my wheel to ensure that everything aligns correctly and I don’t experience shifting?

Thank you

Comment: Why did you need a new wheel if just a cog is bad?

Comment: I had a lot of issues with that wheel so it was best to replace it :)

Comment: You should also check your chain before riding. If your cog was bad it's very likely that the chain is worn as well and will not interface well with a brand new cassette.

Comment: My chain is fairly new I didn’t have the funds at the time to replace the other functional parts

Comment: How new is "fairly new"? If you ran a new chain on an old cassette it can wear out the chain very quickly. There are tools available to check the chain for wear. Or just measure the length of 24 chain pins. It should measure exactly 12" when new. It will get longer as the chain wears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shift the derailleur to the highest position without a wheel in place. Then when you put the new wheel into place, align the chain with the smallest cog.

Comment: just shift it? do i need to do anything with the derailer or will it work itself out

Comment: The spring in the derailleur will move it to the highest (furthest outboard) position when you shift to the highest position on the shifter.

Comment: Once the wheel is on, you may need to adjust the derailleur (high and low limit screws as well as indexing) because the new cassette may be positioned slightly differently than the old one.

Comment: I’m starting to realise why I never attempted to replace my cassette. I’m sure there is videos somewhere about adjusting the derailler

Comment: Yes, there are lots of great videos on Youtube and elsewhere.

Comment: You’re amazing man thank you

Comment: parktool.com is the web site of a big bike tool company and has good-quality "how to" videos for working on different parts of your bike.